# Can not use global variable as argument for jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show a local weather using API. API url generates depending on user's local position.

```
var lat,lon = null;
var key = "mykey";
var api = "";

function setApi(position){
 lat = Math.round(position.coords.latitude*1000)/1000;   
 lon = Math.round(position.coords.longitude*1000)/1000;

 api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + key;
}


navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setApi);

$.getJSON(api, function(data){
  console.log(data.sys.country);
});
```

The problem is nothing happening if I use my **api** global variable as argument for $.getJSON function. It works if I use a string instead. E.g.:

```
  $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=46.295&lon=30.648&appid=%mykey%", function(data){
console.log(data.sys.country);
});
```

Comment: So I would say that `api` is not what you think it is at the time of the call. I would guess it is still `""`. For example, maybe `getCurrentPosition` is failing.. (or maybe it is async.. I am not familiar with it)

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` is not failing. I can access my **api** var via console and it has right value. I guess async can be the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Try moving the call to after you set the `api` value then, if you are so sure it gets that far

Comment: You are right, it works now. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are having is that at the point of calling `$.getJSON`, the actual `api` value is still set to `""`.

This is likely being caused by an async operation in `getCurrentPosition`. Which means that `$.getJSON` is effectively being called before the `setApi` callback function.

I would suggest that based on your current code, the simplest solution would be to just move the `$.getJSON` call inside your `setApi` function, that way you can be sure it is only called *after* the `api` value has been correctly set.

For example:

```
var lat,lon = null;
var key = "mykey";
var api = "";

function setApi(position){
    lat = Math.round(position.coords.latitude*1000)/1000;   
    lon = Math.round(position.coords.longitude*1000)/1000;

    api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&appid=" + key;

    $.getJSON(api, function(data){
        console.log(data.sys.country);
    });
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setApi);
```